# DMS-59 to VGA for Single Monitor?

Tags: display, vga, cable

I got a old graphics card with a [DMS-59 output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59). I'm wanting to use the DMS-59 out to use a single monitor setup. Before I purchase a conversion cable, I wanted to confirm that DMS-59 is suitable for a single monitor setup despite traditionally used for 2 monitors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can always hook up only a single monitor to the DMS-59 adapter. Some adapters have their ports marked "1" and "2", but it usually really doesn't matter which one you use since the Operating System will automatically detect which port is in use.

In fact, in the corporate environments in which I have seen DMS-59 used, there is almost always only a single monitor in use.